# Writing a function to end the program?

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I save the reference of the alarm that was returned when the alarm was set and then cancel the alarm? I need a stop function so the user can end the program.

```
p = ' IDKMYBFFJILL!'
k = 0

def new_char():
    global k
    label.config(text=p[k])
    k = (k+1)%len(p)
    window.after(500,new_char)

def end():
    window.after.cancel(new_char)

from Tkinter import *

window=Tk()
window.title('New char program')

label = Label(window,text='',width=2,font=('Times New Roman',200))
label.grid()

begin_button = Button(window,text='begin',command=new_char)
begin_button.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky='EW')

end_button = Button(window,text='end',command=end)
end_button.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky='EW')

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to capture the output of [`alarm()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method), which is an "alarm identifier", which you can then pass to [`alarm_cancel()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after_cancel-method), i.e. `alarm_cancel(<alarm_identifier>)`.  (Note: the syntax is `alarm_cancel()` with an underscore -- not `alarm.cancel()` like you were trying)

One way to do this would be to encapsulate your alarm functions inside a class, which I call `Alarm`:

```
from Tkinter import *

p = ' IDKMYBFFJILL!'
k = 0

# Create Alarm class
class Alarm(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.alarm_id = None

    def new_char(self):
        global k
        label.config(text=p[k])
        k = (k+1)%len(p)
        self.alarm_id = window.after(500,self.new_char)

    def end(self):
        window.after_cancel(self.alarm_id)

# Create Alarm instance (called alarm)
alarm = Alarm()

window=Tk()
window.title('New char program')

label = Label(window,text='',width=2,font=('Times New Roman',200))
label.grid()

begin_button = Button(window,text='begin',command=alarm.new_char)  # Note change
begin_button.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky='EW')

end_button = Button(window,text='end',command=alarm.end)           # Note change
end_button.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky='EW')

window.mainloop()
```

You could go further and move `p` and `k` inside the Alarm class, eliminating the need for `global` -- but it's not necessary to fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can put stop flag, to indicate when to stop and what to do  after your loop stops:

```
from Tkinter import *


p = ' IDKMYBFFJILL!'
k = 0

stop_loop = False # the stop flag set when cancel is pressed

def new_char():
    global k

    if stop_loop: # execute this when you press cancel
        print("K value when cancel was stopped: ", k)
        return

    label.config(text=p[k])
    k = (k+1)%len(p)
    window.after(500,new_char)

def end():
    global stop_loop
    stop_loop = True # set the flag that you want to stop (done when pressed cancel button)
```